# How to open outlook mail compose window in chrome app?

Tags: javascript, mailto, google-chrome-app

I'm working on a chrome application which needs to create an email on click of a button. I'm using mailto: for that and since default client is Outlook, it should open outlook email compose window. I'm using below code for same -

```
var mail = "mailto:" + recp + "?subject=" + sub;
newWindow = window.open(mail);
```

When this is executes, chrome app opens outlook email window but **also opens a tab in chrome with url as contents of mail variable .** and even if I call close on the newly created tab, that does not get closed. My goal is to create email without any additional  tab.

Is there any way I could achieve this

Comment: What if user is not using outlook? What if user email is opening in same window (like yahoo/gmail in browser)?

Comment: for my use case, it is confirmed that users have outlook on their machine and it is their default email client.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to open new window for this link, since there will be auto-open outlook window (I have no associated action with that type of link, so I get popup to select with that program to open it)

```js
$("span").click(function() {
  var recipient = $(this).text();
  window.location.href = "mailto:" + recipient + "?subject=Mail to " + recipient;
});
```

```css
span {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
span:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>sample@mail.com</span>
<span>another@mail.com</span>
<span>sample2@mail.com</span>
```

Comment: this question is specific to chrome packaged apps. if I use window.location.href, it throws exception that can't open same-window link to "mailto. try target="_blank and If I pass target as _blank, a new chrome tab is opened .